# Can I put my party in a line automatically?

Tags: wasteland-2

Before I enter a battle I often place my party members in a straight line. But it's a bit annoying doing it all by hand by individually selecting each character and putting them in a straight line one by one.

Is there a way to put auto-align my party?
Or put them in a pre set position with a hotkey?

This is before battle starts of course.